# How to open Webstorm projects directly from a folder in Windows Explorer?

Tags: webstorm, shortcut, windows-explorer, project-folder

Is there a way to launch Webstorm so it opens a selected folder in Windows Explorer?

Instead of:

- launching Webstorm (possibly on a different project from its last session);
- closing the current project;
- browsing for the desired project in the project wizard panel;
- finally, opening it.

Something like:

- Setup (a one time thing, per projects) a shortcut to Webstorm with an argument pointing to the given project.
- Then you could just double-click that shortcut to start it off from that project!

Is there anything like this that exists? Or a way to register any folder with an `.idea` subfolder to have an "open with... -> Webstorm" right-click option?

Comment: Another way: if you add IntelliJ to your Windows taskbar, you can right-click it to see the list of recently opened projects and select an entry to open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out.

The icon shortcut works by simply adding the whole path to your project as an argument to the Shortcut Target, like so:

(obviously, you can copy-paste it instead of typing it all by hand)

[image]

If you have multiple shortcuts setup and you open each ones, *as far as I can tell*... it opens them in separate Webstorm windows, leaving the previous one open. So you can jump between projects a bit more efficiently this way.